# Zu sehen vs sehen

Tags: word-usage

I've felt that both of these examples are correct:

*Die Welt zu sehen*

*Die Welt sehen*

I've seen the *zu* be used and omitted in various sentences.

My suspicions are that these have a slight different meaning of:

*To see the world*

*Seeing the world*

I would like someone to confirm of this is correct.

Also, if they are both correct, can they both be used in a normal sentence e.g.

*Die Welt zu sehen ist wichtig für mich*

*Die Welt sehen ist wichtig für mich*

Answer (score 3):

Modal verbs take a bare infinitive:

> Ich will die Welt sehen.

While with other verbs, you need either an object clause:

> Es ist mein Wunsch, dass ich die Welt sehe.

Or, as a shortening of an object clause that shares the subject with the main clause, an infinitive clause, which needs *zu+Infinitiv*.

> Es ist mein Wunsch, die Welt zu sehen.

Simple infinitive clauses may even drop in as a **Prädikativ**, no commas then.

> **Die Welt zu sehen** ist mein Wunsch.